# Warning During Compilation of Gem5

Tags: compilation, warnings, gem5

i am using ubuntu18.04.5 and i have installed all the requisites and successfully compiled gem5 following the guide: https://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/introduction/

But during the compilation I get 2 warnings:

```
*** Summary of Warnings ***
Warning: Header file <png.h> not found.
         This host has no libpng library.
         Disabling support for PNG framebuffers.
Warning: Couldn't find any HDF5 C++ libraries. Disabling HDF5 support.
```

How can I fix them?
how will it affect the user experience?

Comment: `sudo apt install libpng-dev libpng++-dev libhdf5-cpp-100 libhdf5-dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CentOS 8.3, I got the same warning messages while building gem5 -

```
***Summary of Warnings***  
    Warning: Header file <png.h> not found.
             This host has no libpng library.
             Disabling support for PNG framebuffers. 
    Warning: Couldn't find any HDF5 C++ libraries. Disabling HDF5 support.
```

and solved it using the command -

```
sudo yum install libpng-devel
sudo yum -y install hdf5-devel
```

For Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 using the below command -

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```